# Trying to install Ubuntu on a Acer Aspire One AOD255E

Tags: installation

Hi I am currently running Windows 7 starter on my Acer Aspire One AOD255E netbook and I wanted to get rid of windows and use Ubuntu instead. I created an bootable flash drive with the latest version of Ubuntu using unetbootin and when I boot from the flash stick I get a black screen with a blinking cursor and nothing else. I have to hold down the on button to shut the computer off.
Any advice out there... Just keep using windows? :(

Comment: Read the answers in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078). Pay special attention to the answer with the 90+ up-votes. Basically,you need to boot with `nomodeset` parameter passed to the kernel. It's easy, don't panic.

Answer (score 0):

First try and use a live CD to download Ubuntu, they always seem to work better for me. To make a live CD of Ubuntu, simply insert the CD and double click the OS that you should have downloaded to your computer. You can get the OS here, assuming you are running desktop version:

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

If CD's are unavailable, you may want to try a tool to make a live USB:

[LiveUSB download](https://fedorahosted.org/releases/l/i/liveusb-creator/liveusb-creator-3.12.0-setup.exe)

Third off, if none of these are working, Try to enter your BIOS settings by either pressing F12, esc, or c at start up. Then change your round robin boot settings to the appropriate device.